# Azure cognitive search index size estimation

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a Azure search index with many fields (1000 fields).  However for any given document only a few fields have values - maybe 50.  Does that matter when determining how much storage will be consumed by the index?  Do only populated values take up space in the index?

Also a similar question related to the suggester/autocomplete.  If most of my fields are defined to use the suggester, but only a few have values per document, is performance of the index still negatively impacted?

Answer (score 1):

I have several indexes similar to yours. The index schema has 1000-1200 properties and usually only 50 or so properties are populated. In my case 50.000 items takes about 1 GB of storage which should mean about 20kB per item.

My conclusion is that the storage taken by the extra properties is negligible.